# Why doesn't Bead Sort have a theoretical time complexity of O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

How can [Bead Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_sort)<sup>1</sup> have a theoretical time complexity of O(1)?

Wikipedia claims that if every bead moves at the same time, as it would be if you use an abacus to do this sort, then you would have a time complexity of O(1), but wouldn't the distance that the beads have to travel in the worst and average cases still scale with the size of the list?

If I'm misunderstanding the article, what *does* cause O(1) time complexity?

---

<sup>1</sup> Also known as Gravity Sort

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I'm not really a fan of either answer, so I'm accepting neither. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) is the complexity in a model where the beads can all fall an arbitrarily long distance in a fixed amount of time. As the article states, this model does not accurately reflect physical reality.

Answer (score 1):

> How can Bead Sort1 have a theoretical time complexity of O(1)?

When all the beads are ***allowed to fall at the same time parallely*** as in Abacus, then the beads would arrange in an ascending order from top to bottom. This all would happen in constant time, hence the complexity would be O(1).

The arrangement would be a pile of beads arranging in a single-line of Abacus; the same would happen in every line of Abacus, and hence the largest number of beads would settle in the last row, as the last row would consist of beads in every line of Abacus.

This all is happening because of Gravity (not pratically feasible to allow falling of each bead at the same time parallely, but is just a theoretical assumption).

CASE :-

```
*****                          ****
**********         ---->       *****
**************                 **********
****                           **************
// this happens in a short while because beads would settle to the lower surface
// because of presence of Gravity.
```

The distance would not matter here, as it need not be considered for the time complexity measurement.

Wikipedia highlights the impractical case :

> Time-complexity would be O(1): <sup>!</sup>***The beads are all moved simultaneously in the same time unit***, as
>   would be the case with the simple physical example above. This is an
>   abstract complexity, and cannot be implemented in practice.

<sub>! emphasis mine</sub>

Comment: @Smurfton - Check that highlight as in the edit, the situation is impractical to attain, as when *the beads are all moved simultaneously in the same time unit, they would reach ground at the same time* --- This is not a regular physics case!